# How to remove the value within the ranges for negative range in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with four column ["DecimalYear", "NS(cm)", "EW(cm)", "UD(cm)"]. For second, third and fourth column, I want count the value that occurs between two values with step of 1 and removes value within the range which is less then thershold value 2 and replce it with null or space. it is working well with positive values but fails to remove negative values.

```html
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

# Generate dates from 2021/1/1 to 2021/1/9
start_date = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2021, 1, 9)  # Corrected end date
date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DecimalYear", "NS(cm)", "EW(cm)", "UD(cm)"])

# Fill DecimalYear column with dates
df["DecimalYear"] = date_range

# Fill other columns randomly
df["NS(cm)"] = [random.uniform(-4, 4) for _ in range(len(date_range))]
df["EW(cm)"] = [random.uniform(-4, 4) for _ in range(len(date_range))]
df["UD(cm)"] = [random.uniform(-4, 4) for _ in range(len(date_range))]

# Define function to count values between whole numbers with step of 1
def count_values_between(df, column_name):
    column_values = df[column_name]
    min_value = np.floor(column_values.min())
    max_value = np.ceil(column_values.max())
    
    counts = []
    for i in range(int(min_value), int(max_value)):
        count = ((column_values >= i) & (column_values < i + 1)).sum()
        if count != 0:  # Only include if count is non-zero
            counts.append(f"'{i}<{i+1} = {count}'")
    
    return counts

# Count values between whole numbers with step of 1 for each specified column
columns_to_count = ["NS(cm)", "EW(cm)", "UD(cm)"]  # Specify columns here
results = {}
max_length = 0  # Track the maximum length of counts
for column in columns_to_count:
    print(f"Count of values between whole numbers for column '{column}':")
    counts = count_values_between(df, column)
    print(counts)
    results[column] = counts
    max_length = max(max_length, len(counts))  # Update max_length
    print()

# Pad counts lists with empty strings to ensure equal length
for column in results:
    results[column] += [''] * (max_length - len(results[column]))

# Convert results to DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

# Save counts results to a CSV file
#results_df.to_csv("counts_results.csv", index=False)
print(results_df)

# Save the original DataFrame to a CSV file
#df.to_csv("original_dataframe.csv", index=False)
print(df)

def remove_values_within_threshold(df, column_name, threshold):
    column_values = df[column_name]
    min_value = np.floor(column_values.min())
    max_value = np.ceil(column_values.max())

    counts = []
    for i in range(int(min_value), int(max_value) + 1):  # Adjusted range to include the maximum value
        count = ((column_values >= i) & (column_values < i + 1)).sum()
        counts.append(count)

    for i, count in enumerate(counts):
        if count <= threshold:
            if i == int(min_value):  # For the first range
                if min_value < 0:  # If there are negative values
                    mask = ((column_values >= min_value) & (column_values < 0))
                else:
                    mask = ((column_values >= min_value) & (column_values < min_value + 1))
            elif i == int(max_value):  # For the last range
                mask = ((column_values >= max_value - 1) & (column_values <= max_value))
            elif i < 0:  # For negative ranges
                mask = ((column_values >= i) & (column_values < i + 1))
            else:  # For other positive ranges
                mask = ((column_values >= i) & (column_values < i + 1))
            df.loc[mask, column_name] = np.nan


# Set the threshold value
threshold = 2

# Apply the function to remove values within ranges less than or equal to the threshold
columns_to_check = ["NS(cm)", "EW(cm)", "UD(cm)"]
for column in columns_to_check:
    remove_values_within_threshold(df, column, threshold)

# Save the modified DataFrame to a new CSV file
#df.to_csv("threshold_removed_dataframe.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

to show the problem clearly i have attached a image for third column as it declare that value within ranges -2<-1 =2, so it should have remove those value within that ranges as it is less or equal to thershold value and should have not appeared at end, but they do.
[image]

I use the chatgpt to generate code but chatgpt also failed to provide the solutions. how shold i solve this?

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT. It seldom provides correct answers let alone good answers. Few people are going to bother to debug code written by ChatGPT rather than yourself.